# Efficient way to insert a value into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I need to insert a value into an array... ideally I could just start with `List<myObj>`, but the methods I need to use return `myObj[]` instead.

I always need to insert a value into the first position, and rather than worm the values already in the array... I came up with the following scheme..

```
    List<myObj> list = array.ToList<myObj>();
        if (list.Count > 0 && list != null)
        {
            list.Insert(0, InsertRecord(myParam)); // InsertRecord() is one of my methods...
        }
        return list.ToArray();
```

My question is... is this even remotely efficient?  Is there a better way to go about doing what I need to accomplish?

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? How do you read from the List? Randomly? First item? Last item? Enumerate the whole list?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: `ToList` does not in fact create a copy of the array, it uses the `List<T>` constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and wraps it.

Comment: @EdS. I actually meant his ToArray() call at the end... oops. But, am I right there, anyway?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Yes, that one does.  It uses a `Buffer<T>` and the Buffer constructor performs a copy.

Comment: Do you need to *return* an array or *consume* an array (or both)?

Comment: I need to return the array with the newly inserted value in the first position

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can save some time with

```
var newArray = new myObj[oldArray.Length  + 1];    
oldArray.CopyTo(newArray, 1);
newArray[0] = InsertRecord(myParam);
```

Comment: Isn't better to work with a list until you need to return an array and than just call `ToArray` as he is doing. As List `Add` is o(n) only when capacity is reached.

Comment: I think it still has the same bounds, though, even if a potentially better wall-clock. (Assuming Insert is `O(1)` amortized and the copy is `O(n)` and that only one item is added between needing it as an array.)

Comment: There is no way to avoid the O(n) copying here. This answer is just aiming at the lowest overhead. Going through `List<>` just adds a lot of steps.

Comment: @Magnus it depends, it looks like the OP is adding sporadically, so Henk's is better, but you'd be more efficient if there were several inserts in a row.

Comment: I was going to answer it then saw this. I agree with Henk. That is a different name, "Henk".

Comment: If you going to go with this approach, rather than increase the size of the array by 1 each time you add a new value, double the size of the array then keep track of where the first record is. If this approach is used you will probably want to shrink the array after a certain number of records have been removed, this would usually be done by halving the size of the array when the array size is greater than 4n.

Comment: @firthh: not in this scenario. Read the part about the confining API.

Comment: @firthh It seems trivial but I only need to insert into the first position of the array and I only need to do it once. Since that is the case, increasing the size of the array by 1 does actually make sense

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ok, I didn't take enough notice of the constraints, I was just thinking of ways of decrease the amortized cost of this operation.

Answer (score 3):

The `List<T>` class is backed by an array, so there is no difference in performance between using a List to insert at index 0 and using an array to insert at index 0, except that the BCL developers have tested far more extensively for performance.  Don't take the performance hit of the `ToList` method and `List<T>` constructor, since a new array allocation is happening behind the scenes anyway.

Worse, you might need *two* array allocations with your posted code, since the `List<T>` constructor (called by ToList) may allocate an array of exactly the size of `array`, and then the `Add` method has to allocate a new array just to perform the insertion.  Unlikely, but possible.

In short, allocate the new array yourself.

**EDIT:**

Given that your method needs to return an array, it doesn't make any sense at all to go through a list.  With a list, you are going to copy the original array into the array backing the `List<T>`, then insert, then copy that backing array into another array to be returned from your method.  That makes two array allocations minimum, plus the possible third that I mentioned above.  Using raw arrays guarantees exactly one array allocation.